# Want to call webservice by javascript or jquery without any c# code

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-services

I want to access asp.net web service by only javascript / jquery with out any c# code..
I have generated simple web service like below..

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
[WebMethod]
public string TestNameService(string name)
 {
    return "data-" + name;
 }
```

On the other domain I am using textbox and button to send request and on label I want to display out put. 
 Like this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="call_service" runat="server" Text="Call Service" OnClientClick="CallService(); return false;" />
<asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" Text="" />
```

---

I had tried with this jquery which is working in same domain.. but  i am not able to access method on multiple domains and if i access method then i get only blank response

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function CallWebService() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://......myurl..../WebService.asmx",
                data: "{'name':'" + $("#txt_name").val() + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: ShowData,
                error: error

            });
        }
        function ShowData(data, status) {
            $("#lblMsg").html(data.d);
        }
        function error(request, status) {  
            alert(request.statusText);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried with jquery ajax method to call webservice?

Comment: @mayur yes i have tried but it was not working..

Comment: What you are getting error?

Comment: nothing just getting blank response..

Comment: Post your Ajax code. then i can help you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46810/discussion-between-mayur-borad-and-shirish)

Comment: See in my answer, i have provided my script..

Comment: @Brad larson - It is not the question which u had edited.. it is also an answer because it is working in same domain. i want to run in multipal domain so i had write in answer so other users can use..who have requirement to run web service through java script in same domain.. if u have answer then say other wise don't edit question because u had changed the direction of question..

Comment: @Brad Larson i don't have any problem. some of users want to know my script for same domain so i have posted as answer to get modified answer for multiple domains. and do you know any thing about this question? u can see the same answer with jquery which was given by mayur borad. that ans is also working for same domain. Brad i m still waiting for answer if u know any answer then give answer except modification of question & comments. i had posted script as answer because i want different ideas from users in place of same script ideas so if possible then keep my question/ans as it was. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using cross domain, you have to specified to jquery with follows

```
$.support.cors = true;
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://......myurl..../WebService.asmx",
                data: "{'name':'" + $("#txt_name").val() + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: ShowData,
                error: error

            });
```

let me know if not works.

Comment: I have tried this but i m getting same problem at now it is showing --> ReferenceError: CallService is not defined
if i add call service in url then it is also giving same problem.. like --> http://......myurl..../WebService.asmx/TestNameService

Comment: If you have't 3rd party webservice then put break point on Application_BeginRequest Event of Global.asmx of your webservice project. If you have't this event, create it. and check your debugger point is fired ?

Comment: I have run on my local server and i m getting 2 problems in this if i add service name in url then i am getting '500 Internal Server Error - http://---url---/WebService.asmx/TestNameService"'
and if i simple run web service then shows - '405 method not allowed web service - http://---url---/WebService.asmx"'

Comment: Can you open your webservice? Are u opening it with localhost?

Comment: Are getting breakpoint on Global.asmx when you make ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

Your normal javascript ajax request will fail because your solutions seems to be on different domains if I understand your question.

You will need to use a technique called [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), which is supported in the .NET platform as well, see:

http://encosia.com/using-cors-to-access-asp-net-services-across-domains/

Comment: thanks for the reply, but as per requirement i have to do it with simple javascript / jquery..  and i have seen this, it is same like my script.. in my script i am not able to access method and if i access method then i get only blank response..

Comment: @Shirish With CORS enabled you will be able to do it with javascript only

Comment: ok i will try, because i had never worked with this CORS so i have to read all thing.. did u have seen my script? do u have any idea in this script?